# Tricky selection in COGNOS

Tags: compare, substring, selection, where-clause, cognos

I have a table with a list of part numbers in Column A. There exist what I will call "raw numbers" (12345), and "7-" numbers, which start with "7-" and then just add a raw number onto the end (7-12345). I am trying to select only the "7-" numbers for which a raw number also exists upon removing the leading two characters.

I am having trouble defining WHERE conditions to make sure that the "7-" part numbers selected also have a corresponding raw number which exists in the same column (some "7-" numbers do not have a corresponding raw number in the table - I only want those which do).

Once I have identified these pairs, I need to compare a value in Column B of the "7-" part number with a value in Column C of the corresponding "raw" part number. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My current thought process: create a table with only 2 columns: 1) the "raw" portion of the "7-" number. 2) the Column B data that I need to compare later. The WHERE condition ensures only 7- numbers are selected while the SELECT statement cuts off the leading two characters. 

Once that table is created, I will select only the part numbers from my initial table WHERE the part number column (A) = Column 1 in my new table (the raw component of the 7- numbers). This way I am only selecting pairs, and I can get the original columns B and C onto the same row in order to compare them. Feasibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to use two queries in Cognos.   One query will get you the partnumbers that start with '7-', and the portion of that part number with the '7-' removed.

```
select
pn.partnum,
right(pn.partnum,len(pnpartnum) -2) as Trimmed
from
partnumbers pn
where
pn.partnum like ''7-%'
```

Your second query will just get you all part numbers not starting with '7-'.

```
select 
* from 
partnumbers 
where partnum not like '7%'
```

The you will add a join query, and use these two queries in it, resulting in something along these lines:

```
select
query1.partnum,
query2.partnum
from
(
select
pn.partnum,
right(pn.partnum,len(pnpartnum) -2) as Trimmed
from
partnumbers pn
where
pn.partnum like '7-%' ) Query1

inner join
(select 
* from 
partnumbers 
where partnum not like '7%') Query2
on query1.trimmed = query2.partnum
```

Here's a grossly over-simplified [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e9f6/12) example.

Comment: Thanks for the example, it helped a lot. I was able to get the 7- numbers which have corresponding raw numbers into an output. In addition to that, I need the raw numbers which do not have corresponding 7- numbers (but not raw numbers which do). If you look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/afedc/60), I essentially want to take all the duplicates in the first column of my output and only keep the row which contains the 7- number in the second column. I tried doing an EXCEPT command with the UNION, excluding the output of the joined Queries 1&2 but it didn't work...  Ideas?

Comment: Wow, that's a lot harder that I expected.  I think this is what you're looking for, or at least on the right track, but it sure is ugly. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/afedc/81)

Comment: In the example you sent me, only 4 of the 8 "7-" part numbers were saved because the base number on each of the other 4 was greater than 7. But in looking at the data for my actual application, I have 0 cases of base numbers starting with 7 or greater! So this works for me, thanks so much. Exactly what I was hoping to achieve by adding the "base number" column.